# Is IIS (Internet Information Services) Affecting Localhost

Tags: windows-10, localhost, iis

After the April Windows 2018 update, my localhost is now only showing a blank screen.

After a bit of research I found that it may be the IIS (Internet Information Services).

I've now checked the `ISS Management Console` under `Web Management Tools` in `Windows Features`, and `Internet Information Services (ISS) Manager` is showing up in `Administrative Tools`.

However, localhost is still showing a blank screen.

I've gone back into Administrative Tools and restarted `Internet Information Services (ISS) Manager`, but this still doesn't fix the problem.

Is there a step that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

The IIS bindings to the used website have probably been updated. See screenshot below, go to the IIS manager, click on your website under "Sites" - in my case "Default Web Site" and click on "Bindings" on the right side of the screen.

[image: IIS Manager Site Binding Settings]

If there is an entry that does NOT tell "*" or "localhost" but rather an IP-address, then that is probably your issue. "localhost" normally refers to 127.0.0.1. If there's an IP-Address of e.g. your server set, then it will not work. Set * (=All Unassigned) to listen to all interfaces - including localhost.

Comment: Thanks Felix. I've checked this and it's showing a * for `http` on `Port 80`

Comment: Please check `netstat -a -n -b` on the server and try to identify the service (.exe) that is listening to the http-port. The entry should begin with 0.0.0.0:80 and remote addr of 0.0.0.0 - status "Listening". Just to make sure it's really IIS that is listening here. Also please check if IPv6 is enabled on all interfaces (if no, enable it and restart). Which OS are you using? Please also check the `%SystemDrive%\Windows\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR` or other logs in that folder for errors / infos when you make a request

Comment: If you use the -b switch with netstat, does it show which process is blocking the port 80? is it really the IIS? Please check the logs from the directory I posted above directly after restarting the IIS service for errors and probably even eventlog